# How to return to the previous page from a Visualforce page?

Tags: visualforce, custom-object, custom-button, opportunity, commandbutton

I have a page that shows records for an object and I need to be able to select some, and then once the "Add Packages" button is clicked I need the page to return to the previous page after completing it's function in Apex.

I attempted to try getting the  retURL but getting that doesn't seem to be working.

I also tried to use the standardController.cancel(); page reference but that doesn't seem to work due to the rerender on the button, which needs to be there to pass the variable.

Does anyone have any suggestions on this?

**Visualforce:**

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity_Package__c" extensions="MetadataPackageEditor" sidebar="false" showHeader="false">
  <apex:outputPanel id="all">
  <apex:form >

      <apex:outputField value="{!Opportunity_Package__c.Opp_Package_Rel__c}"/>

      <apex:pageBlock title="Select Package(s)">
      <apex:pageMessages />

          <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!packages}" var="o" id="table">
              <apex:column title="Select" headerValue="Select">
                  <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!o.selected}"/>
              </apex:column>
              <apex:column value="{!o.pack.Name}"/>
              <apex:column value="{!o.pack.Products__c}"/>
              <apex:column value="{!o.pack.PPU_Discount__c}" headerValue="Price per Unit Discount"/>
          </apex:pageBlockTable>
      <apex:commandButton value="Add Packages" action="{!processAndAddSelected}" rerender="all">
          <apex:param name="oppIdParam" value="{!Opportunity_Package__c.Opp_Package_Rel__c}" assignTo="{!oppId}"/>
      </apex:commandButton>
      <apex:commandButton action="{!cancel}" value="Cancel"/>
      </apex:pageBlock>



  </apex:form>
  </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: did you decode the `retUrl`?

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: <apex:page controller="MyController123">
    
    <apex:form id="all">
            
            <apex:commandButton action="{!callme}" value="callme" oncomplete="myActionMethod();return false;" rerender="all">
                <apex:actionFunction name="myActionMethod" 
                                     action="{!submitEmp}" />
             </apex:commandButton>
             <apex:outputLabel Value="Value"></apex:outputLabel>
            <apex:outputText value="{!textValue}" ></apex:outputText>
            
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>

Comment: public class MyController123 {

    public String textValue { get; set; }

    public PageReference callme() {
        textValue  = 'Hi Friend';
        
        return null;
    }


    public PageReference submitEmp() {
        textValue = textValue + ' How are you';
        PageReference pgref=new PageReference ('/'); //frame you url where the page should land
        
        return pgref;
      // return null;
    }

}

Comment: So I see you put in how to call an actionFunction, but this doesn't particularly help. I have absolutely no idea what needs to be done to get the proper url from retURL and the resources for it are just shoddy.

Comment: PageReference pgref=new PageReference ('/'); This lands me on home page, similarly when u call cancel to which page it will be taken. suppose it is the opportunity u creeated the  PageReference pgref=new PageReference ('/'+{!OppId}); it will land me on that opportunity

Comment: Okay so in the dev console it gives an error that this is a sandboxed instance and doesn't have permission to use that call.

Answer (score 5):

Why not using JavaScript? Either you can store the previous URL in [localStorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) and go back there later with document.location **or** try simply to use

```
window.history.back()
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_his_back.asp

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but it only returns a blank white page now

Comment: the above will not work if you have any action on the page and then click the back button

Answer (score 2):

try this,

```
PageReference returnPage = new PageReference(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('retURL'));
```